# $.ajax not execute jquery code from php

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to execute a jquery code from a php page called by ajax.

Change html of div.error

Here's the code(If there is an easier way just tell/post):-no $.load

HTML/jQuery: jquery.js already linked

```
<input type='text' id='test'>
<div id='error' style='display:inline-block;'>CHANGE HERE</div><bR>
<input type='submit' value='run' id='button'>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$('#button').click(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: "test="+ test,
    success: function(jqXHR){
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('error');
    }
});
});
</script>
```

test.php

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('#error').html('working');
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here ?

Comment: The purpose of ajax is to use javascript(client side processing) to send a request to the server(php server side processing) without causing a refresh. In your case you are asking the server to run client side scripts which will not work.  Your `test.php` file should have php code that produces output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `test` variable that you are using doesn't seem to be declared anywhere. Try hardcoding first. Also the `{key:value}` syntax is preferred as it ensures to properly url encode the value when sending to the server:

```
data: { test: 'some value' }
```

and if you want to use a variable, make sure you have declared it:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var test = 'foo bar';
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { test: test },
        success: function(data) {

        },
        error: function() {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
```

Also if you want the javascript to execute in your php script remove the `<script>` tags:

```
$('#error').html('working');
```

and specify the `dataType` parameter to `script` in your `$.ajax` call:

```
dataType: 'script'
```

Another possibility is to have your `test.php` script simply return the value:

```
working
```

and then inside the success callback refresh the DOM:

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#error').html(data);
},
```

Comment: yeah forgot to add that in but im just trying to get the div to change

Comment: Sure, but ensure that you write valid javascript for that purpose. If you don't declare the variables you are using you will get a javascript error and your script simply won't run.

Comment: The `test` variable *may* exist.  He has an element with an id of `test`.  Some browsers will make that into a variable.  Which means he may be posting `test=[object HTMLInputElement]` :-P

Comment: OK, see my updated answer. Specify `dataType: 'script'` to your $.ajax call and also remove the `<script>` tags from your `test.php` and leave only the jquery code.

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript from inside `test.php` won't run because you've never told it to.  It's not just gonna run because you loaded it.  It needs to be in the DOM to run.

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: "test="+ test,
    success: function(data){
        $(data).filter('script').appendTo('head');
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test.php script should output what you want to display.

it should look something like:

```
echo "<html>";
echo "<div>working</div>";
echo "</html>";
```

so that it returns something.  Right now, you are returning only javascript.